# android create public file

Tags: android, logging, android-file

I want to output logcat to `logs.log` file. Its working fine i can open it with application FileManager in Android. But i cannot access it if i connect my phone to computer. How to make file visible in computer ?

```
try {
   File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/logs.log"); 
   filename.createNewFile(); 
   String cmd = "logcat -d -f "+filename.getAbsolutePath();
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
}   catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to copy the log file from device to computer

```
adb pull /sdcard/logs.log {your_computer_dir}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is that external storag (sdcard) is not availble from device when device is connected to PC and sdcard is mounted on it.
Here is documentation quote:

> Caution: External storage can become unavailable if the user mounts the external storage on a computer or removes the media, and there's no security enforced upon files you save to the external storage. All applications can read and write files placed on the external storage and the user can remove them.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

But you can take that files from mounted sdcard directly on your PC.